# Spinner Adapter - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, spinner, adapter

I have a problem with the `adapter` for my `spinner` that takes data from a **SQLite Database** and tries to show a bunch of strings as a result of the spinner.

It sends me the following error message:

> "Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown." 
>  
>   when I click on the spinner with the app running, if it wasn't in a try/catch the application would freeze.

Can someone help me find where the problem is ? Code below:

Code of the Activity

```
private string[] _companyNames;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.a_plant);

            Spinner spCompanyName = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spCompanyName);
            EditText etPlantName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etPlantName);

            Button btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
            Button btnSearch = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSearch);

            //Adds data to the spinner only if they dont exist already
            DBManager.LoadCompanySpinner(_companyNames);

            //shows data on spinner
            try
            {
                //THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS CAUGHT
                ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, _companyNames);
                //
                adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
                spCompanyName.Adapter = adapter;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

`DBManager` Code to add data on the `spinner`

I believe this code works since it prints on the console the results.

```
//insert data in spinner
        public static void LoadCompanySpinner(string[] l)
        {
            var t = DBManager.Instance.Query<Company>("Select CompanyName from company");
            int size = t.Count;
            if(size > 0)
            {
                l = new string[size + 1];
                l[0] = "Select Company...";
                for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    l[i + 1] = t[i].CompanyName;
                    Console.WriteLine("added " + t[i].CompanyName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you checked every item on that line for a non-null value?

Comment: @Jason can you tell me how do I do that please ?

Comment: use the debugger to add a breakpoint on that line and check each value

Comment: @Jason it just doesn't let me go through the adapter creation line, it throws the excpetion the first time i go through it

Comment: You don't go through it, you stop ON it and check each argument.

Comment: @Jason oh I see , thank you for the tip

Comment: If you have solved this issue, please share solution to answer and accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: I still have not found a solution but I figured that the null value was the array I created inside the activity, it doesn't recieve the reference therefore it's always null

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it!

I changed the `array` to `List<string>`, because the error was in the `string[] _companyNames` since I never assigned a `Length` the value would always be Null therefore leading to a:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException

I could never used a array with a static length because I will always need to add new values, so a list with a dynamic length should be the best option.

This is the final result:

On the activity ->

Changed: `private string[] _companyNames;` to `List<string> _companyNames = new List<string>();`

and the Global Activity did some changes so it would work with a list:

```
public static void LoadCompanySpinner(List<string> l)
        {
            var t = DBManager.Instance.Query<Company>("Select CompanyName from company");
            int size = t.Count;
            if(size > 0)
            {
                l.Add("Select Company ... ");
                for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    l.Add(t[i].CompanyName);
                    Console.WriteLine("added " + t[i].CompanyName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you for the tips!

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.